# Magento: Getting Warning in log file, php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am Getting the Warning on system.log file,Any way to fix this ?

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  in lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 129
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related with  mysql version, sometime  mysql container doesn't start properly

Please try this solution with your server support team (Workaround: you should downgrade the MySQL container from mysql:latest to mysql:5.6 and rebuild the container with the docker-compose build --no-cache mysql command and restart the container)